# Add-OdbcDsn to add MySQL odbc unicode driver configuration using powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, odbc, windows-server-2019

I'm new to powershell script and windows server and trying to add MySQL ODBC unicocde 5.2 driver 32 bit configuration in Windows Server 2019. I can able to add data source name in MySQL connector.

```
$rds="rds.xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "DemoModel" -DriverName "MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver" -DsnType "System" 
-Platform '32-bit' -SetPropertyValue @("Server=rds", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", 
"Database=demo-v4")
```

When I run above powershell script, it add Data Source name in MySQL Connector and it doesn't added rds enpoint.

[image: Mysql connector odbc driver configuration]

However I failed to add AWS RDS end-point and its credentials with database name. I need to select parameters such as Allow big result sets, Enable automatic reconnect and Allow mutliple statements  in Connections section and Return matched rows instead of affected rows in Cursors/Results section.

[image: Connections parameter]
[image: Cursors and Results parameter]

How to configure data base credentials in ODBC MySQL connector in Windows Server 2019 using powershell script? Can any one please help me to achieve?

Comment: Can any one please help me? Or Does this question is wrong?

Comment: does this question is wrong? I still searching solution for this.

Comment: Try configure manually and look at `Get-OdbcDsn -Name 'MS Access Database' | Select -ExpandProperty PropertyValue` - Maybe you'll find interested props

Comment: Try Set-ODBCDriver after you use OdbcDsn.  Each driver has different properties defined in the driver.  So you first must set add the driver and then set custom properties.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/set-odbcdriver?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: I can able to add-odbcdsn using this command. Add-OdbcDsn -Name "DemoModel" -DriverName "MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver" -DsnType "System" -Platform '32-bit' -SetPropertyValue @("Server=rds.xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=one_demomodel") -PassThru.

Comment: However, When i set-odbcdsn using this command, its not working. Set-OdbcDsn -Name "DemoModel" -DriverName "MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver" -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("SERVER=rds.xxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "DATABASE=one_demomodel"). Its throwing error "Set-OdbcDsn : Cannot find driver (Installer error code: 7)."

Comment: Why will you need those configuration parameters?

Comment: @RickJames, we are trying to configure those things using AWS SSM Powershell scripts. So we don't want to configure manually inside Windows Server. That's why I'm looking this automation option.

Comment: Did you try @filimonic suggestion. I actually had a similar need (but for Postgres) and this  was perfect. I configured one manually, then used Get-OdbcDsn to get the parameter and use `Add-OdbcDsn` to configure the driver with the correct property values (there was a lot). The only thing I had to do was to remove some of the default keyvalues that looked like 'PropertyName=' without  value as the `add` cmdlet expected a `key=value` format. No need to use the `set` cmdlet IMO

Comment: @SagePourpre ,HI I tried. I can able to get the values using Get-OdbcDsn. But I failed to apply some parameters like uname, password, dbname, rds endpoint. But I can able to add data source name. Can you please share your postgres method? I will refer and try to create.